# Возвращение данных от сервера после ajax-запроса

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Никак не могу разобраться с ajax. Делаю корзину. Запрос отправляется index.php, где в контроллере есть условие:

```
if($cart == 'add_item'){
    add_to_cart($par_id, $par_qty);
    $_SESSION['total_sum'] = total_sum($_SESSION['cart']);

    //количество товара в корзину + защита от ввода несущетвующего параметра товара

    $_SESSION['total_quantity'] = 0;
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] AS $key => $value){
        if(isset($value['color_id'])){
            // если получен цвет товара из бд - сцммируем

            $_SESSION['total_quantity'] += $value['qty'];

        }else{
            //иначе удаляем такой праметр из сессии

            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);

        }
    }
    cart();
    exit;
}
```

Создаётся массив $_SESSION с ключом ['cart'], в конце есть функция `cart();` она формирует строку html самой корзины, то есть в цикле проходит по массиву $_SESSION['cart']. По идее, сервер должен вернуть эту строку, но не возвращает. Не могу понять, где я ошибся.

Отправляю данные на сервер так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('#add_to_cart').click(function(){

            var selected = $('.selected'); // Определяем переменную
            var color_section_id = selected.attr('data-color'); // Определяем переменную
            var select_body_item = $('#select_body_item_' + color_section_id + ' option:selected'); // Определяем переменную
            var parameter_id = select_body_item.val(); // Определяем переменную
            var input = $('.qty_input_wrap input'); // Определяем переменную
            var qty = input.val(); // Определяем переменную
            var cart_input = $('#cart_input_' + parameter_id);
            var cart_input_val = cart_input.val();
            var cart_input_qty = cart_input.attr('data-cart-item-qty');
            var item_qty_sum;
            item_qty_sum = parseInt(qty) +  parseInt(cart_input_val);
            if(parameter_id != 0 ){

                if(cart_input_val == cart_input_qty && cart_input_val || item_qty_sum > cart_input_qty){
                    $('#cart_item_qty').text(cart_input_val);
                    $('#cart_item_stock').text(cart_input_qty);
                    $("#modal_window_cart_stock_error").fadeIn(250);
                    setTimeout(function() { $("#modal_window_cart_stock_error").fadeOut(250); }, 2000);
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://store.torawhite.ru/",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ({
                            cart: 'add_item',
                            par_id: parseInt(parameter_id),
                            par_qty: parseInt(qty),
                            success: function(data){
                                $('#cart_content').hide().fadeIn().html(data);
                                $("#modal_window_cart_add").fadeIn(250);
                                setTimeout(function() { $("#modal_window_cart_add").fadeOut(250); }, 2000);

                            },
                            error: function(){

                            }
                        })

                    });

                }


            }else{
                $("#modal_window_cart_error").fadeIn(250);
                setTimeout(function() { $("#modal_window_cart_error").fadeOut(250); }, 2000);
            }

        });

    });
```

Данные проходят, массив создаётся, но новое содержимое корзины не вставляется. Корзина обновляется только после обновления самой страницы.

Comment: может как-то так должно быть $result = cart(); echo $result; exit();?

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, спасибо, но так тоже пробовал - не возвращает

Comment: значит в функции cart() нет оператора return или возвращаемая переменная просто пуста. что говорит var_dump($result)?

Comment: Да, `return' нет. там просто выполнение кода идет. Чтобы что-то вернуть, нежно же поместить строку в переменную, поместить код же в нее нельзя

Comment: нужно вывести возвращаемое значение оператором echo, на страницу куда обращаетесь за ответом. строку можно вернуть в явном виде, массив лучше в json упаковать

Comment: То есть ещё раз сделать, как вы изначально предложили? про json только слышал...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34459/discussion-between-dmitry-ongamer-and-torawhite).